# How can I get a username from the TikTok API

Tags: api, tiktok, tiktok-api

I have searched for many days now, but didn't found a field in the TikTok API where I can get the username of the user that has connected his TikTok account with my website. I want to let user log in with their TikTok account to let them link it from my website to TikTok and want to display their "@" name (not the display name. I can only get their IDs etc. but no their username. If anyone can help I'd be very happy!

I searched on many forums for this but didn't sound any solution. I'm expecting to be able to send a request to the official TikTok API which then replies the username of someones ID or of someones Token I own.

Answer (score 4):

On [Get User Info](https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/tiktok-api-v2-get-user-info/) API route you can put `username` on **fields** arguments like this :

```
https://open.tiktokapis.com/v2/user/info/?fields=profile_deep_link,username
```

This field `username` is not documented (maybe a mistake in TikTok side) but it work well for me, you can see the screenshot :
[image]

Comment: Not working. When adding "username" field TikTok API v2 reply with:
"Error: TikTok Api Error: Invalid field username"

Comment: It's strange, it's still working on my side. Just tested right now.

Comment: Confirmed that adding `username` in fields works for me. Tested in 2024/02/12

Answer (score 0):

As the TikTok API only provides the display name, the only workaround we have found so far is to fetch the videos of your user, and parse the share-url to extract the username from the first video. You just have to pray that he has got at least one.

Query the videos of your user:

`curl -L -X POST 'https://open.tiktokapis.com/v2/video/list/?fields=share_url' -H 'Authorization: Bearer XXXXX' \ -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \ --data-raw '{ "max_count": 1 }'`

Here, the token you provide tells the API which user you are talking about.

The share-url looks like this:
`https://www.tiktok.com/@USERNAME/video/VIDEO-ID?utm_campaign=tt2d_open_api&utm_source=aaaa`